# Cannot able to display the list through jsp

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

This is the jsp page

```
     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>All Employees</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Employees List</h1>
    <table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">
    <tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th></tr>
    <c:forEach  items="${list}" var="student"> 
    <tr>
   <td>${student.id}</td>
    <td>${student.username}</td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <br/>

</body>
</html>
```

This the Controller

```
 @RequestMapping("/userDetails")  
    public String userDetails( ModelMap m){  
      List<Student> users= studentService.studentDetails();
        m.put("student",users);
        return "userDetails";  
    }
```

> `here i am not able to display the data in the view page .Any suggestions are welcome Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put an attribute keyed by string "student" in the model

```
m.put("student", users);
```

but refer to a collection named "list" in your JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="student">
```

Make these consistent.

e.g.

```
m.put("students", users);
<c:forEach items="${students}" var="student">
```